# É possivel fazer dois Selects num Try?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try {
    Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gym", "root", "0000");
    PreparedStatement inst = lig.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM produtos_has_historico WHERE Produtos_idProdutos AND Historico_idHistorico");

    ResultSet a = inst.executeQuery();
    while (a.next()){
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement(a);
    }               
} catch(Exception e){}
```

Vou buscar o `idHistorico` e o `idProduto`, mas eu queria também ir buscar o nome e o preço, que está na outra tabela `produtos`. Posso acrescentar ao `try` outro `Select`?

Comment: Sim, você pode.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode colocar várias queries no mesmo try, e especificamente neste seu caso que está usando para o catch a exception genérica, pode utilizar outros métodos que disparem uma throw, circundada no mesmo try, a única coisa que obrigaria você a criar outra catch, não seria nem um novo try, mas uma nova catch, conforme o exemplo abaixo, seria caso sua primeira exception não contemplasse o requerido para a segunda, para caso de try/catch específicos como se por acaso utilizasse uma SQLException no primeiro catch e um IOException por exemplo, aí teria que declarar da seguinte forma:

```
try{
 //código
}catch( SQLException sqle){

}
catch(IOException ioe){
}
```

Mas como seu código você utiliza a Exception pai, pode declarar qualquer código dentro da try, que será disparada a mesma exception para qualquer erro. O único infortuno que terá, será para processar de forma seletiva a exception ou interceptá-la que creio não seja seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Não seria mais facil você utilizar o **JOIN** para obter esses dados e retornar para seu objeto? Você poderia fazer dessa maneira

```
 public List<Status> pesquisarComboAtendimento(int idPerfil) throws SQLException, NamingException
{
ArrayList<Status> listaSelect = new ArrayList<Status>();

listaSelect.add(new Status(0, "Selecione"));

try (Connection con = pool.getConnection(); PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select s.* from TBPERFIL_STA ps inner join TBSTATUS s on s.ID_STATUS = ps.ID_STATUS and s.ST_NOVA = 0 and s.st_conclui = 0 and s.st_aprova = 0 and (not exists (select * from tbdpto dpto where dpto.sta_atend = s.id_status)) where ps.ID_PERFIL = ?");)
{

    pstmt.setInt(1, idPerfil);

    try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); WebRowSet webRowSet = new WebRowSetImpl();)
    {
    webRowSet.populate(rs);
    while (webRowSet.next())
    {
        Status status = new Status(webRowSet.getInt("id_status"), webRowSet.getString("ds_status"), webRowSet.getBoolean("st_nova"), webRowSet.getBoolean("st_aprova"), webRowSet.getBoolean("st_conclui"));
        listaSelect.add(status);
    }
    }
    listaSelect.trimToSize();
}

return listaSelect;
}
```

Tenho esse exemplo para ilustrar o que você poderia fazer, acima você realiza um join nas tabelas que deseja recuperar seus dados depois preenche seu resultSet com esse retorno.